# Barlow points and Gauss points

Tags: post-processing, finite-element-analysis

Are all Gauss points (integration points) also Barlow points (optimal locations to extract stresses during post-processing stage)? I am guessing no. Only for some very specific elements this might be true. If not, do any commercial FEM codes use Barlow points instead of Gauss points to extract stresses?

Comment: All the packages I knew (NASTRAN, MARC) used integration points to evaluate all element quantities (temperature, stress, strain).  I never encountered one that used Barlow points.  I stopped doing FEA for a living in 1995.  I don't know what the current state of the art is.  No experience with ANSYS.

Comment: NAFEMS link: https://www.nafems.org/terms/BARLOW-POINTS/.  Looks like Gaussian points are best for primitives like triangles and tetrahedra; reduced points are better for quads and bricks.